# Controlling the numbering of section titles

Tags: sectioning

Now i need to attach an endnote to the number of the beginning of section 16, and naive manipulations like `\section{\endnote{$\pi=3.14$}}` will make a big gap between the number 16 (which is automatically generated) and the mark of the endnote, therefore I changed it to `\section*{16\endnote{$\pi=3.14$}}` which consequently makes the number of the next section (which is section 17) 16. I don't want to adjust following sections' titles manually, so is there a way to attach the endnote/footnote? Or generally is there a way to control the sequence of numbering of the titles?

A minimal example

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section*{1\footnote{In this section we take $c=0$}}%This one being the title of the first section.
This is the material of the first section.
\section{}%This is the title of the supposedly second section
This is what is contained in the second section.
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you want help, please provide a minimal example, http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228. Then we know what you are starting out from and also have something to start debugging on.

Comment: Where does `\endnote` come from. From the equally named package?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer aye.

Comment: @daleif Is has been done so.

Comment: Just to clarify: You want to attach the footnote marker directly to the section header's number rather than place it, say, at the end of the section header?

Comment: I am confused: In the OP running text, it is `\endnote`, whereas in the code block `\footnote`?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - I think the footnote/endnote thing is a red herring: If the `endnotes` package is loaded, normal footnotes (i.e., those created by `\footnote`) are converted to endnotes automatically. The major issue seems to be the OP's attempt to attach a footnote (or endnote) marker directly to the section's number. Of course, I may not have understood the objective correctly.

Comment: @Mico: Thanks for the information about `\endnotes` (never used it so far), but I do not understand the objective too.

Comment: @Mico I don't think that just loading `endnotes` makes all footnotes become endnotes. In order for this to happen, the package documentation tells to type `\let\footnote\endnote` in the preamble.

Comment: @egreg - You're right about footnotes becoming endnotes automatically once the endnotes package is loaded. That said, I still think this posting is not about footnotes being positioned at the bottom of a page or somewhere later in the document, but about the (shall we say, *slightly* unusual) positioning of the footnote (or endnote) marker.

Comment: Are your sections without a title or do they have one? In other words, do you always have `\section{}` with nothing in the braces?

Comment: @egreg They don't have titles, but only numbers, which are usually automatically generated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution, where `\@seccntformat` is hijacked to add an endnote marker. The endnote text is provided as a trailing optional argument to `\Section`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse,endnotes}

\NewDocumentCommand{\Section}{somo}{%
  \gdef\thissectionnote{}% reinitialize
  \IfValueT{#4}{\gdef\thissectionnote{#4}}% set up the endnote
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\section*{#3}} % starred section
    {\IfNoValueTF{#2} % unstarred section
       {\section{#3}} % no optional argument
       {\section[#2]{#3}}% optional argument
    }%
}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{%
  \csname the#1\endcsname
  \ifcsname #1@seccntformat\endcsname
    \ifx\thissectionnote\@empty
    \else
      \unexpanded{\makebox[0pt][l]{\endnotemark}}%
      \noexpand\endnotetext{\unexpanded\expandafter{\thissectionnote}}%
    \fi
  \fi
  \quad
}
\def\section@seccntformat{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\Section{A title}

This is a normal section

\Section{Another title}[In this section we take $c=0$]

This section has an endnote.

\Section[Short title]{Long title}

This is another section.

\theendnotes

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you need to use `\section` because the text is automatically generated, you can save the meaning of `\section`: just the part with `\NewDocumentCommand` needs a change.

```
\let\latexsection\section
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{somo}{%
  \gdef\thissectionnote{}% reinitialize
  \IfValueT{#4}{\gdef\thissectionnote{#4}}% set up the endnote
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\latexsection*{#3}} % starred section
    {\IfNoValueTF{#2} % unstarred section
       {\latexsection{#3}} % no optional argument
       {\latexsection[#2]{#3}}% optional argument
    }%
}
```

Comment: I have an idea: `\phantom{\section}`. If we can start a section whose title does not appear but the number counts, the next section's number will automatically be adjusted at the right place, and it works. But the cmd gives error message (albeit that it works)

Comment: @WilsonofGordon I have added the workaround for being able to use `\section` instead of a new command.

Comment: (continue) the error message reads

Comment: ! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.4 \phantom{\section}
                      
? 
! Too many }'s.
\makeph@nt ...color@begingroup #1\color@endgroup }
                                                  \finph@nt 
l.4 \phantom{\section}
                      
? 
[1

Comment: Thanks for the lengthy response, but I feel myself failed to understand it. What is the package `xparse` for?

Comment: @WilsonofGordon It's for having a very flexible tool for managing *-variants and optional arguments.

Comment: Oh why don't we just add to counter?

Comment: @WilsonofGordon Do you mean `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}\protect\footnotemark}`? No, thanks. `;-)`